# Android: Dynamically change a variable

Tags: android

Is there a way to dynamically change a variable?  For example, this is what I am trying to do.

I have this:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
```

This is in a do while loop.  What I want to do is change the actual variable tv every time it loops so I dont keep writing over the previous textview.

I have tried various ways, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me as is.  Please explain what you are trying to accomplish, and more importantly, show the code of that loop you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to be able to refer to all the TextViews at the end of the loop, but you only have access to the last one made?  If that's the case, make an array of TextViews and add the new TextView to the array on each iteration.  That way, you'll be able to access each one by its array index.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array of TextViews, I assume at the end of the loop (or during the loop) you want to add all of the TextViews to your layout. This code assumes you want to add the textviews during the loop, and YOU KNOW HOW MANY ITERATIONS THE WHILE LOOP WILL PERFORM

```
LinearLayout myTextViewLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linear_Layout_Name_In_Xml);
int iterations = THE_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS_YOUR_WHILE_LOOP_WILL_PERFORM;
TextView []myTextViews = new TextView[iterations]; //Array of TextViews to use as references
int i = 0;
while( your_condition ){
TextView textView = new TextView(); //declare a new TextView
textView.setText( YOUR_TEXT_HERE );
myTextViewLayout.addView(textView); //add textView to your UI 
myTextViews[i] = textView; //save Reference to your new textView in an Array
i++;
}
```

Now you have access to those textViews in your array.